# How to convert value type by another value's reflect.Type in Golang

Tags: go

How to convert value type by another value's reflect.Type in Golang
maybe like this:

```
func  Scan(value interface{}, b string) error {
    converted := value.(reflect.TypeOf(b)) // do as "value.(string)"
    return nil
}
```

How can do this properly in golang?

Comment: You can use `reflect.ValueOf(interface{})` to get a `reflect.Value` object representing the actual object. I'm not sure what you're trying to do, can you elaborate?

Comment: ok, I will make it more detailed @Not_a_Golfer

Comment: In general you can do `converted := reflect.ValueOf(value).Convert(reflect.TypeOf(b))`. But that doesn't help you much, as you probably want to actually copy the value of b into a, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way to get a typed value out of an interface is to use a type assertion, and the syntax is `value.(T)` where T is a type. There's a good reason for this, because it makes the type of the type assertion expression computable: `value.(T)` has type T. If instead, you allowed `value.(E)` where `E` is some expression that evaluates to a `reflect.Type` (which I think is the gist of your question), then the compiler has no way to (in general) statically determine the type of `value.(E)` since it depends on the result of an arbitrary computation.